# Отправка XML запроса и вывод результатов

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, post

Запросом POST нужно спросить:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request><userLogin>123</userLogin><userPassword>123</userPassword></request>
```

Сервер ответит:

```
array (
'error' => '0',
'errorDescription' => 'No errors',
'userLogin' => '123',
'userPassword' => '123',
'userID' => '4',
'userBALANCE' => '1065',
'userPERIOD' => '10.01.2012 00:00 - 08.02.2012 23:59:59',
'userTARIFF' => 'Администраторский',
)
```

Как мне это все сделать через Ajax/jQuery?

Comment: Вообще, обычно, перед отправкой XML данных они как-то шифруются, во всяком случае если речь о бес-сервисе. 

Если же нет - тогда используйте JSON, это и проще в написании и легче по трафику.

Answer (score 1):

Передавать данные на сервер в виде XML это изврат, но если уж серверный скрипт под это заточен, то можно так.

Код на клиенте:

```
var xmlData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request><userLogin>'+userLogin+'</userLogin><userPassword>'+userPassword+'</userPassword></request>';
$.ajax({
  "url": "/login.php",
  "type": "post",
  "data": {
    "xmlData": encodeURI(xmlData), // xmlData должен быть преобразован в URI-совместимый вид, хотя возможно, что jQuery делает это сам
  },
  "dataType": "json", // этот параметр означает тип данных, ОЖИДАЕМЫЙ ОТ СЕРВЕРА
  "sucsess": function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);

});
```

Сервер в любом случает получает строку запроса в единственном формате:

```
xmlData=%3C?xml%20version=%221.0%22%20encoding=%22UTF-8%22?%3E%3Crequest%3E%3CuserLogin%3E123%3C/userLogin%3E%3CuserPassword%3E123%3C/userPassword%3E%3C/request%3E
```

Ответ сервера можете формировать в [XML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php), но я рекомендую [JSON](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).
Код на сервере:

```
$xmlData = $_POST['xmlData'];
// ...
// До этой строки не должно быть никакого вывода
header("Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8");
$response = array( /* ... */ );
echo json_encode($response);
```

---

RTFM!

Answer (score 0):

Гы.

Отсылаем серверу данные. [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

в ответ серверный скрипт, допустим **user.php** должен обработать данные посланные ему, ну и отдать нужные данные тебе.

В каком формате он тебе должен отдать выбирай сам, JSON, массив, текст, тут что удобнее тебе.

Вот собственно то что тебе нужно сделать.

***ps обязательно в XML слать данные? или это ты сам придумываешь себе такие штуки?***

Comment: @Shrek насколько я понимаю это веб-сервис и такую штуку придумал не ТС, ее придумали очень давно

Comment: @AlexWindHope ну возможно, не спорю.

Суть ладно не в этом :)

Ждем кода от ТС

Answer (score 0):

Друзья, это я понимаю, мне просто стыдно выкладывать те скрипты, которые я уже писал для решения этой задачи - они не работают. Я был бы очень признателен, если бы Вы помогли мне написать клиентский скрипт. Серверный есть.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    function show() {

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://api.*****.ru:81/query.php",
            data: "<request><userLogin>123</userLogin><userPassword>321</userPassword></request>",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (html) {
                $("#result").append(html);
            }

        });

    }

    show();
    setInterval('show()', 3000);

});
```

Этот в див с id=result ничего не пишет. Пустота. Сервер выдает массив, как его разобрать этим скриптом я просто не понимаю ;(

Comment: Я могу поругаться?
Дай серверный скрипт!

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо перед отдачей массива конвертировать его в json-объект. Тогда уже в ЖабаСкрипте Вы с легкостью сможете работать с JSON

Comment: как? я этого не умею ;(

Answer (score 0):

Вы наверно еще и данные собирали по частям из формы?

```
$.post('url.php', $("form").serialize(),function(data){alert(data)},'json');
```

Comment: нет, данные я прописываю ручками.. тут без форм..